# Using the default Times font in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, times, timesfont

Is there any way to use the old Times font (triggered by `\usepackage{times}` in pdflatex), along with other fonts in XeLaTex?

I know I can use Times New Roman or TeX Gyre Termes, but neither of them look exactly the same, and I prefer the old font.

The main difference w.r.t. Termes is most likely in kerning -- see below how a page rendered with both options looks like in the 3rd paragraph of the main text.

Rendered with `\usepackage{times}`:
[image: A sample page rendered with \usepackage{times}]

The same text rendered with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`:
[image: A sample page rendered with \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}]

Comment: originally `times` used adobe times roman postscript font, but `ptm` is now mapped to the urw nimbus Times clone whch was the base used for Termes. It's not clear how old you mean (or what difference you see)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle – I looked more closely and the difference is most likely mainly kerning (see above)

Comment: if you use `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}\usepackage{times}` you can use exactly the same 7-bit ascii Times subset with luatex that pdftex would use. So it depends how much you are prepared to give up to get the classic tex emulation.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, that's exactly what I wanted! Could you please just copy&paste this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
 \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}\usepackage{times}
```

You can use exactly the same 7-bit ascii Times subset with luatex that pdftex would use. So it depends how much you are prepared to give up to get the classic tex emulation.